# Site wise custom evaluator in alfresco

Tags: alfresco-share

I am facing some problems to create,
 Site wise evaluator to show or hide create menu option in alfresco.

In below Attached image i want to show create market option for one site and create project option for other site.
can anyone help me regarding this, if possible please provide sample custom evaluator code.

i am using Alfresco 5.0.d version  [image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2012/03/05/share-configuration-extensibility/) describes how to to the site evaluator for updating Alfresco Share configuration. Judging from your screenshot you are already able to create and add multi-select actions for the Document Library. You just need to place your configuration within extension modules as described in the blog post.

Comment: Hi Dave,  i am using alfresco 5.0.d version, and that blog is available for alfresco 4.2 , and also its not working in my case. thats why i posted it once again. please reply. or tell me the way how can i do this. may be i am doing in wrong way. please tell me the steps how can i use that out of the box evaluator

Comment: Hi Dave, Its working fine. Now i got one more challenge,that is now i want to show the create button only inside Document Library. Means if i will Enter into the sub folders of Document Library, then i want to hide Create and also  upload Button. Can you please suggest the way, how can i do this. Thanks in advance.