# How to create site wise custom evaluator to show or hide Create menu Doclib Actions

Tags: alfresco-share

How to create site wise custom evaluator to show or hide "Create" MENU Doclib Actions for specific site.

I have two options in create menu. now my requirement is,  i want to show first option for one site and second option for other site.

for that i need to write site wise custom evaluator.

so can anyone please help me, how can create that custom evaluator and how can i apply it to my custom configuration in custom model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Site wise custom evaluator in alfresco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717779/site-wise-custom-evaluator-in-alfresco)

Comment: You're effectively already asked this question once here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717779/site-wise-custom-evaluator-in-alfresco - the answer is the same - you don't need a custom evaluator, all of the information is provided in the answer to that other question. There is a site evaluator available out-of-the-box - you just need to use your configuration with the example from the linked blog post.

Comment: Hi Dave,  i am using alfresco 5.0.d version, and that blog is available for alfresco 4.2 , and also its not working in my case. thats why i posted it once again. please reply. or tell me the way how can i do this. may be i am doing in wrong way. please tell me the steps how can i use that out of the box evaluator

Comment: The example is also applicable to 5.0.d as well as 4.2. Maybe you could provide the XML for the module configuration that you've created so that we can see why it might not be working?

Comment: It's working now,  i did it in some different way, But its working now.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you should post the solution then for the benefit of others finding your question in the future?